# default value to select one menu after validation error

Tags: jsf-2

Can a default value "Select One " be set to SelectOneMenu component after a validation error in the phase listener `afterPhase()` method?

Right now if the default value  "Select One" is selected and form is submitted

```
<h:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
```

The select one menu value is changed to previously valid value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the item value non-empty (and non-null!) and set the `noSelectionOption` attribute to `true`.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="none" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

*(and fix the `h:selectItem` to be `f:selectItem`)*

Comment: If I select Select One option, it does not throw a validation error now.Can I use any hibernate validator to validate the selectOneMenu field instead of a custom validator checking for none value?

Comment: So, `@NotNull`/`@NotBlank` doesn't kick in? Interesting... At least, you could just put `required="true"` on the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.